# Reset form to pre validation state?

Tags: angularjs

We are new to angular and we wanted to use angular validations with our forms. We are using async ajax calls with a kendo grid to get, create, edit and save data without any submit. I am having a hard time figuring out how to reset the validation state of the form when the user chooses to create a new record.

I made this small exaple, trying anything I could find in sof without any luck so far:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.4/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ValidationController">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
      <label>
        Name
        <input name="nombre"
               ng-model="field"
               required />
      </label>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error">
        <div ng-message="required" ng-if="myForm.nombre.$touched" ng-messages-include="myMessages">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" ng-click="reset(myForm);" value="Reset">reset validation</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myMessages">
      <div ng-message="required">required field</div>
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']).controller("ValidationController", function ($scope, $window) {
      $scope.reset = function (form) {
        form.$setPristine();
        form.$setUntouched();
        form.$setValidity();
        form.nombre.$setPristine();  
        form.nombre.$setValidity();
        form.nombre.$setUntouched();
      }
    });
</script>
```

Here is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yh9q1a2j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I think this better suits your needs. I've updated the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/n7qqn1x6/6/

In your reset method call $setPristine along with clearing the formData object.

```
$scope.formData = {};
$scope.myForm.$setPristine();
```

To get the error messages to be removed from the page once added I had to use ng-show instead of ng-if

```
<div ng-show="myForm.nombre.$error.required&&myForm.nombre.$dirty">required</div>
```

Comment: Your button is inside the form, so it's also trying to submit the form, causing the validation error. If I understand your need correctly you should separate your reset form method from the act of submitting the form, so it happens after a successful submission.

Comment: I took the button outside of the form and used your aproach but the error message doesn't go away. I already tried this before too, this doesn{t clear up error messages.

Comment: @Ziul I updated my answer and made some updates to my fiddle that I think will help.

Comment: If you type something and remove it the error messages shows up, Nothing in your fiddle shows how to get rid of it to reuse the form.

Comment: I see, the only way I could prevent that is to use ng-show instead of ng-if/ng-include on the error message. fiddle updated

Comment: Oh, I just started with angular so I am not sure if this is intended behaviour or not. Supusedly, the ng-include is an improvement to reuse messages: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages but besides those short snippets, is really hard to find more detailed documentation.

Comment: I've updated again moving the ng-show, allowing you to continue using ng-include if you'd like. Edit: Actually it looks like this doesn't work.

Comment: All right, thanks for your time but just one last question (you don't really have to answer it), do I forcefully have to use a submit button to trigger error messages?

Comment: You don't, if you remove "&&myForm.nombre.$dirty" from the ng-show on the error message, the message will show anytime the form field is in an invalid state.